# spring: return JSON from controller as ModelAndVIew

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

How can I return JSON from spring controller as a view or `ModelAndView`? I am not interested in using `@ResponseBody` annotation. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Spring has `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`, which can dynamically return "right" view based on suffix  or `Accept` header. [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations). You provide both model and view in `ModelAndView`, let Spring do the view resolution.

Answer (score 38):

Yes, you can return a [`MappingJacksonJsonView`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html) or assign it to a `ModelAndView` object using `mav.setView(new MappingJacksonJsonView())`.

Update: In Spring 4 MappingJacksonJsonView is [deprecated](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html#MappingJacksonJsonView--). You might want to upgrade to [MappingJackson2JsonView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJackson2JsonView.html)

Comment: To elaborate, you can set the MOdelAndView's view name to an instance of MappingJacksonJsonView to return a JSON object in place of the ModelAndView. An example would look like:

`ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(new MappingJacksonJsonView());
mav.addObject("key1", "value1");
mav.addObject("key2", "value2");`

Returning `mav` would then output a JSON object of the form:
`{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}`

Comment: Update: I used [MappingJackson2JsonView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJackson2JsonView.html) for the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` class for writing json strings to output stream. Use the following code snippet in method of your controller:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(outputStream, model);
outputStream.flush();
```

Comment: If your version of Spring is high enough, then the MappingJacksonJsonView object uses Jackson's ObjectMapper to serialize the model.  Reference http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html