# SpringMVC Restful Web Service

Tags: web-services, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am trying to build a RESTFUL Web Service however I am getting an error under is my code:

**jsp**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        <%@ include file="../css/forms.css" %>
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <%@ include file="../js/off_reg.js"%>


        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#userName').blur(function(evt){


                CheckAvailability();                    
            });
        });         

        function CheckAvailability(){

            $.ajax( {
                  type:'GET', //Could be 'get' depending on your needs
                  url:'validateUserName.htm',
                  data:{userName:$('#userName').val()},
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success:function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                  }
                });

    }



    </script>
```

**DAO**

```
public boolean OfficerExist(String userName){


    try{

        logger.debug("About to check if officers existing");

        String sql = "SELECT userName FROM crimetrack.tblofficers WHERE userName = ?";

        logger.info("at this point 1");

        //String dbUserName = (String)results.get("userName");

        String dbUserName = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{userName},String.class);


        logger.info("after JdbcTemplate");

        if (dbUserName.equals(userName)) {

            logger.info("User Name Exists");
            return true;

        }else{
            logger.info("User Name Does NOT Exists");
            return false;
        }


    }catch(Exception e){

        logger.info(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

**FireBug Console Error:**

```
GET http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/validateUserName.htm?userName=hello

500 Internal Server Error
    70ms    
jquery.min.js (line 2)

"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack            /validateUserName.htm?userName=hello"
```

**TomCat Error Log:**

```
    com.crimetrack.web.OfficerRegistrationController.validateUserName(java.lang.String,com.crimetrack.business.Officers,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap) throws java.lang.Exception
306270 [http-8084-1] DEBUG com.crimetrack.web.OfficerRegistrationController  - Inside Controller validateUserName
306270 [http-8084-1] DEBUG com.crimetrack.web.OfficerRegistrationController  - The user name that came in is hello
306270 [http-8084-1] INFO  com.crimetrack.service.ValidateUserNameManager  - Inside Do UserNameExist
306270 [http-8084-1] DEBUG com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcOfficersDAO  - About to check if officers existing
306270 [http-8084-1] INFO  com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcOfficersDAO  - User Name Found 1
306270 [http-8084-1] INFO  com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcOfficersDAO  - User Name Found 2
306270 [http-8084-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL query
306270 [http-8084-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT userName FROM crimetrack.tblofficers WHERE userName = ?]
306270 [http-8084-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
306285 [http-8084-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [hello], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
306289 [http-8084-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
306289 [http-8084-1] INFO  com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcOfficersDAO  - Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
306289 [http-8084-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver  - Resolving exception from handler [com.crimetrack.web.OfficerRegistrationController@a32cdd]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid handler method return value: false
306289 [http-8084-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver  - Resolving exception from handler [com.crimetrack.web.OfficerRegistrationController@a32cdd]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid handler method return value: false
306289 [http-8084-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver  - Resolving exception from handler [com.crimetrack.web.OfficerRegistrationController@a32cdd]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid handler method return value: false
306290 [http-8084-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1cbab62
306290 [http-8084-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Could not complete request
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid handler method return value: false
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.getModelAndView(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:438)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
306290 [http-8084-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'crimetrack-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/crimeTrack/validateUserName.htm]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[crimetrack]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[28ms]; status=[failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid handler method return value: false]
306290 [http-8084-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/crimeTrack/validateUserName.htm]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[crimetrack]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[28ms]; status=[failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid handler method return value: false]
```

**OfficerRegistrationController**

```
package com.crimetrack.web;


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.crimetrack.business.Login;
import com.crimetrack.business.Officers;
import com.crimetrack.service.DivisionManager;
import com.crimetrack.service.GenderManager;
import com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation;
import com.crimetrack.service.PositionManager;
import com.crimetrack.service.ValidateUserNameManager;

@Controller
public class OfficerRegistrationController {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
    private DivisionManager divisionManager;
    private PositionManager positionManager;
    private GenderManager genderManager;
    private Officers officer = new Officers();

    private ValidateUserNameManager validateUserNameManager;

    Map<String, Object> myDivision = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> myPosition = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> myGender = new HashMap<String, Object>();



    OfficerRegistrationValidation validateData = new OfficerRegistrationValidation();

    @InitBinder("officers")
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
        //removes white spaces 
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));

        //formats date 
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        //By passing true this will convert empty strings to null
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);

        binder.setValidator(new OfficerRegistrationValidation());

    }


     @RequestMapping(value="officer_registration.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView loadPage(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response,@ModelAttribute Officers officer, BindingResult result, ModelMap m, Model model) throws Exception {     


         try{            

             logger.debug("In Http method for OfficerRegistrationController");


                myDivision.put("divisionList", this.divisionManager.getDivisions());


                myPosition.put("positionList", this.positionManager.getPositionList());


                myGender.put("genderList", this.genderManager.getGenderList());

                model.addAttribute("division", myDivision);
                model.addAttribute("position", myPosition);
                model.addAttribute("gender", myGender);

             return new ModelAndView("officer_registration");            


         }catch(Exception e){

            request.setAttribute("error",e.getMessage());
            return new ModelAndView("error_page");           
         }       
     }

     @RequestMapping(value="officer_registration.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView handleRequest(@Valid @ModelAttribute Officers officer, BindingResult result, ModelMap m, Model model)throws Exception{

         if(result.hasErrors()){

             model.addAttribute("division", myDivision);
             model.addAttribute("position", myPosition);
             model.addAttribute("gender", myGender);
             return new ModelAndView("officer_registration");

        }else{

            return null;
        }   

     }

     @RequestMapping(value="validateUserName.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public boolean validateUserName(@RequestParam String userName, @ModelAttribute Officers officer, BindingResult result, ModelMap m)throws Exception{


         try{

             logger.debug("Inside Controller validateUserName");
             logger.debug("The user name that came in is " + userName);

            if (validateUserNameManager.DoesUserNameExist(userName)== true){

                 return true;
             }

                 return false; 

            // return true;


         }catch(Exception e){

             logger.debug("Error in validateUserName Controller " + e.getMessage());
             return false;

         }


     }



     public void setDivisionManager(DivisionManager divisionManager){

         this.divisionManager = divisionManager;
     }

     public void setPositionManager(PositionManager positionManager){

         this.positionManager = positionManager;

     }

     public void setGenderManager(GenderManager genderManager){

         this.genderManager = genderManager;
     }



    /**
     * @return the validateUserNameManager
     */
    public ValidateUserNameManager getValidateUserNameManager() {
        return validateUserNameManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param validateUserNameManager the validateUserNameManager to set
     */
    public void setValidateUserNameManager(
            ValidateUserNameManager validateUserNameManager) {
        this.validateUserNameManager = validateUserNameManager;
    }




    /**
     * @return the officer
     */
    public Officers getOfficer() {
        return officer;
    }



    /**
     * @param officer the officer to set
     */
    public void setOfficer(Officers officer) {
        this.officer = officer;
    }


}
```

Comment: The log indicates the error is the value being returned by the OfficerRegistrationController.  You probably should include the code for that class.

Comment: @Todd Gibson i included the contents of the Controller. I am not totally sure if i am calling the web service properly from the jsp. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Spring's `@RequestMapping` documentation:

> Any other return type will be considered as single model attribute to be exposed to the view, using the attribute name specified through ModelAttribute at the method level (or the default attribute name based on the return type's class name otherwise). The model will be implicitly enriched with command objects and the results of ModelAttribute annotated reference data accessor methods.

Because this method has the ModelAttribute annotation on an Officers object, the return type is expected to be an Officers object.

You probably want this method to return void, and write to the response object yourself.  (To do that, you will need to add an HttpServletResponse parameter to your method.)

Alternatively, you could return a JSON view.  See [spring: return JSON from controller as ModelAndVIew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173093/spring-return-json-from-controller-as-modelandview)

For example:

```
public View validateUserName(@RequestParam String userName, ModelMap m) {

    // Do validation

    m.addAttribute("isValid", validationResult);

    return new MappingJacksonJsonView();

}
```

Comment: i modified the method signature to  @RequestMapping(value="validateUserName.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public boolean validateUserName(@RequestParam String userName)throws Exception{

Comment: all i need to get returned is true of false. I am noticing in my error logs nothing is getting passed this point dbUserName = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{userName},String.class); I am not sure if i am getting the value out of the resultset into dbUserName correctly

Comment: Do you get the same stack trace now that you have changed the method signature?

Comment: Http 500 - ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid handler method return value: false
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.getModelAndView(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:971)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:438)

Comment: tomcat error log: 29987 [http-8084-3] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
29988 [http-8084-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver  - Resolving exception from handler [com.crimetrack.web.OfficerRegistrationController@18f5630]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid handler method return value: false

Comment: I really think its the dbUserName = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{userName},String.class); because i set a message just after this line and i dont get any, the function does not go on to evaluate if the results from the database matches the parameter

Its being called in the controller so maybe that's where the exception is thrown

Comment: OK...yes, that is throwing an exception, but then you are catching it in the controller.  You can focus on fixing that if you want, but you will STILL get the same exception thrown by the controller method.

Comment: Once you fix the invalid return type, then you will get another exception saying it can't find a view.  You really want the controller method to return void and write "true" or "false" to the response yourself.  You could also use a JSON view to return true or false as a JS primitive, but that will probably require some more configuration.

Comment: Also (if you insist on returning something) I think it needs to be a Boolean object, not a primitive.

Comment: Can you guide on on the method of using Json how will i write that in the view. I will try making the controller method void and returning true of false let you know how that goes. I appreciate your help alot

Comment: I did an ajax function in my view above can you tell me if it was written properly? i was trying to return the Boolean value as json above.

Comment: I don't want to return a view since its a validation function that is executed when you tab out if the field. I just want to return a value like a Boolean

Comment: You're right i needed to return a view and that worked i just returned a view. I evaluated the results from the DAO in the controller and returned to the view form there. I think all i need to do is set an attribute value on the page in my case 'data' then use jquery to evaluate it and then manipulate the DOM.

Comment: can you tell me how can i set the value of 'data' from the Controller. Presently i am using  return new ModelAndView("officer_registration", "data", true); but this doesn't work

Comment: When i get back to the jsp the content of 'data' is the html contents that make up the entire page. I would just like to set the value of 'data' from the Controller and then from jquery set an alert

Comment: You need to return a `MappingJacksonJsonView`, instead of your officer_registration view.  The default behavior of this view is to convert all your model attributes to JSON.  So...you would just need to create a model with a single "data" attribute with a value of true or false.

Comment: Can you guid me to an example of what your saying how it will be typed. I am now doing some work on it here and i change my function to public @ResponseBody String validateUserName i set the string to true or false and it works. How is this working for a String and not a Boolean is it because a String is a complex data type ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are running this query:

```
SELECT userName FROM crimetrack.tblofficers WHERE userName = 'hello'
```

The query runs successfully, but there is no record in the table matching `userName = 'hello'`, so an empty result set is returned. Creating the officer then fails because there is no officer to create and that condition was not handled.

Run the query standalone and confirm there is no such record. Then look at your mapping code and see how this condition should be handled.

A follow up... The java docs for [JdbcTemplate.queryForObject](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) state:

> This method is useful for running static SQL with a known outcome. The
>   query is expected to be a single row/single column query; the returned
>   result will be directly mapped to the corresponding object type.
>
> ...
>
> Throws: IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException - if the query does not
>   return exactly one row, or does not return exactly one column in that
>   row

So you this should not be called if you are not assured of a record in the db, otherwise the line:

```
String dbUserName = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{userName},String.class);
```

needs to be wrapped with a try-catch to handle this case.

Comment: I did place the code in a try block and the function is suppose to return false based on my query. However i am still getting - org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid handler method return value: false

Comment: FireBug error is :GET http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/validateUserName.htm?userName=xzdc 
500 Internal Server Error
  63ms

Comment: @dev_darin Did you confirm that the username 'hello' is in your database and if it is not, have you tried the url with a username that is in the database? If you are using an ide, put a breakpoint on the `queryForObject` line and see if that is not the root cause.

Comment: i do not have the username in the database so its suppose to return null and the function will return false either in an if...then...else condition or in the exception. Ok i will do that and get back to you thanks for your advice thus far.