# Spring return JSON / XML / JSON-P based on suffix

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have set up my controller so that it will return the data in the format as requested through HTTP Accept-Type header set by the client:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonJSONMessageConverter" />
            <ref bean="jaxbXMLConverter" />
            <ref bean="jsonpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Sample controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public TestObject executeTest()
{
    TestObject t = ...
    // not important, generating t
    return t;
}
```

so for example they will do: http:// someurl/test

It works perfectly just fine **if** the client can actually set Accept-Type. Now that's where the issue starts when client is unable to set Accept-Type header, I would rely on the url to be suffixed, for example:

- http:// someurl/test.xml
- http:// someurl/test.json
- http:// someurl/test.jsonp?callback=fn

My challenge is how to configure Spring properly to do this?

Some suggestions:

- use some static method to return json: [Return JSON or View from Spring MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917329/return-json-or-view-from-spring-mvc-controller)
- use ResponseEntity [In Spring MVC, how can I set the mime type header when using @ResponseBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471584/in-spring-mvc-how-can-i-set-the-mime-type-header-when-using-responsebody)
- use default views: http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/03/28/spring-mvc-tip-returning-json-from-a-spring-controller/

and many others, but none of the solution seem to be able to satisfy what I need in a nice, clean why. Ideally I would like to be able to do something clean like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test.xml", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public TestObject executeTestReturnXML()
{
    TestObject t = executeTest();

    return t; // somehow magically force Spring converter to convert it to XML
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public TestObject executeTestReturnJson()
{
    TestObject t = executeTest();

    return t; // somehow magically force Spring converter to convert it to JSON
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test.jsonp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public TestObject executeTestReturnJsonP(@RequestParam(value = "callback", required = true) String callback)
{
    TestObject t = executeTest();

    return t; // somehow magically force Spring converter to convert it to JSON-P with callback wrapper
}
```

Suggestions and/or directions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring MVC 3.0+ introduced the [`ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html) which has the exact functionality you seek.

> Implementation of ViewResolver that resolves a view based on the request file name or Accept header.

This blogpost can help you on your way: http://blog.springsource.org/2013/06/03/content-negotiation-using-views/

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful and I got it working after reading both blog posts.

Comment: If @ResponseBody annontation is used, ViewResolver is unrelated. (I'm not sure)

Comment: You are indeed right. The thing is that @ResponseBody might not be flexible enough for the given goal. The ContentNegotiatingViewResolver gives you that flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the @Produces annotation, introduced with spring 3.1. Have a look at the actual docs http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces
and in the Spring Jira ( https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7213 ) for some background