# Using Spring, return view on success, plain text String on fail

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc

I have a Spring controller and that returns a String that is interpreted as a JSP view. If this method fails, I would like to return a plain text String fail message (as if I was using `@ResponseBody` annotation).

Is this possible? I basically need the presence of `@ResponseBody` to be dynamic.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917329/return-json-or-view-from-spring-mvc-controller

Comment: Or try a more elegant solution with content negotiation: https://spring.io/blog/2013/06/03/content-negotiation-using-views